# Compile Svelte components from SvelteKit and serve to non-Svelte app from dist folder

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

When using a Svelte project with Rollup, if I run `rollup -c`, I can embed the compiled JS into a `<script>` tag and start using my components on HTML pages outside of the project.

Is it possible to do the same with a SvelteKit project (running Vite?). When I run `vite build`, I see there is a `dist/` folder, but I don't see any of my components compiled into there when I do CTRL + F for their names.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what SvelteKit is supposed to be doing for me, but I'm hoping to precompile my Svelte components and serve them from a CDN so other users can use my components inside basic HTML pages without needing run my Svelte component library through a build process.

Comment: SvelteKit is probably not the right tool for that. It attempts to be an application framework, handling routing state, etc.

If you just want a component library you probably can set up Vite independently to compile Svelte components.

Comment: See ["Custom element API"](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api) in the _svelte_ [sans kit] docs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: Custom elements, I tried to get that set up but had a lot of trouble getting Svelte and Storybook to play together nicely when compiling to custom elements. If there's any alternatives to Storybook that would let me do this easier, I'm all ears